# Plone 5 TinyMCE's reference field slowness

Tags: plone

I'm running a fresh instance of Plone 5 on a production server and using Firefox.  I've added about 50 content objects to the site.

When I open TinyMCE and use the reference feature, it is EXTREMELY SLOW.  I can barely type because it keeps locking up.  Result lists are taking anywhere between 3-5 seconds to appear.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please give more details, OS and hardware. Also tell us if there aren't any msgs/errors on the browser javascript console. Can you make the site available online so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Is the browser locking up or are you saying the server takes that long to respond with the results?

Comment: Server takes 3-5 seconds to respond.  Even with caching and it is having issues.  There are no errors in the js console and no errors thrown from the logs.  The server hardware is brand new and running Centos 7 with Varnish.